# Create rest api in slim php

Tags: php, rest, slim

Im trying to create a rest api in slim.php. What i want is actually just two function. one for retrieving all records from a table as JSON. and one for retrieving a record by its ID.

This far my index/api file looks like this below. Now how do i connects do the database? How do i return it as json?

```
<?php
require 'Slim/Slim.php';

\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->get(
    '/',
    function () {
        echo "hola!";
    }
);

$app->run();
```

Comment: Slim is just a routing engine, it does not contain a database abstraction. So you would need to write your own, using built in functions (PDO, MySqli) or use any other popular ORM. Alternatively, use a slightly less 'slim' framework, such as fatfreephp (personaly recommended) or silex

Comment: Thanks for your input! I will mainly use it for routing since I'm building small rest api.

Comment: I always work with [idiorm/paris](http://j4mie.github.io/idiormandparis/) when I develop applications with slim.

Answer (score 1):

I have manage to get something going. I get the result back, but not as pure json. I can't see it as son in the console. Even tjo it gets written out in the browser. Current code:

```
$app->get('/', function () {
    $db = connect_db();
    $result = $db->query( 'SELECT * FROM test;' );  
    while ( $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
});
```

Comment: Nevermind. added `$app->contentType('application/json');` and got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

A restfull route will look something like :

```
api/resources // to get all records
api/resources/{id} // to get a specific record
```

If you're using MVC architecture then in your controller you'll have two methods, one to get all records and the other to get a specific record. I'm not sure which interface Slim implements to connect to database but you can google it.

to return your result as json, you can use PHP's built-in function `json_encode` :

```
// $result = SQL query
return json_encode($result);
```

And I think you should think about paginating your recovered data, because returning a big number of data as json is not a good practice.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you. This helped me to get started!

Comment: Anytime @user2952238 ;)